# go back and forth a string-array with two buttons

Tags: swift

I want to show the first item on viewdidload() and then have the user go to the next item in the array and have the option to go back and disable the back button if it’s the first index and disable the button if its the last index. Here is my code

```
@IBAction func back(_ sender: Any) {
   c -= 1

   if c == thkrArray.count{
       nextButton.isEnabled = false
   }
   if c == 0{
       backButton.isEnabled = false
   }
   let thkr: String = thkrArray[c]
   Text1.text = thkr
```

}

```
@IBAction func A2(_ sender: Any) {
   c += 1

   if c == thkrArray.count{
       nextButton.isEnabled = false
   }
   if c == 0 {
       backButton.isEnabled = false
   }
   if c > 0{
       backButton.isEnabled = false
   }
   let thkr: String = thkrArray[c]
   Text1.text = thkr
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is to add an observer to `c`:

```
var c: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        Text1.text = thkrArray[c]

        backButton.isEnabled = c > 0
        nextButton.isEnabled = c < thkrArray.count - 1
    }
}

@IBAction func back(_ sender: Any) {
    c -= 1
}

@IBAction func A2(_ sender: Any) { // isn't this `next`?
    c += 1
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    c = 0
}
```

Comment: One suggestion - ensure the new value of `c` is a valid index into the array. It can be set by code other than the two buttons.